# Working With/Processing Audio in Java

Tags: java, audio

Anyone know of any good tutorials or reference guides for working with Audio in Java? I'm not looking for anything too specific at this point; just would like to get my feet wet working with audio. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Multimedia/audio support in Java is not great.

But—if you're set on Java, I suggest taking a look at the [Java Sound Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/). It explains most of the basic APIs. Then check out [Java Sound Resources](http://www.jsresources.org/) to get a better idea of how things work. Even though it's not brand-new anymore, it is very useful and explains a lot about the low level details.

Beyond the raw sound API, Sun came up with JMF, the Java Media Framework. It has been unsupported for years, so I would stay clear of it. You might want to use it for inspiration, but I can't recommend using it for more.

You will also discover that the built-in Java support for audio formats like mp3 or ogg is rather limited. To be able to play such files, you will need third party libraries, like jogg, jflac, mp3spi, or [SampledSP](http://www.tagtraum.com/sampledsp.html). While the first three are pure Java solutions, the last one is basically a thin Java wrapper for a number of native libraries. Especially for [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) there are a many different libraries like that, as FFmpeg supports most available audio formats.

The only way to play an mp3 file from Java without any additional libraries, is to *cheat* and use the JavaFX class MediaPlayer. You can find more info about how to do that on Stackoverflow.

Good luck!